# ParametricPlot takes longer time while working with root objects

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

I have the following Mathematica code:

```
$Assumptions = {r \[Element] Reals, r >= 0, rh \[Element] Reals, 
   rh > 0, Q \[Element] Reals, 
   Q >= 0, \[Alpha] \[Element] Reals, \[Alpha] >= 0, 
   P \[Element] Reals, P >= 0, L \[Element] Reals, L > 0, 
   l \[Element] Reals, l >= 0, r0 \[Element] Reals, r0 >= 0};
S[rh_, \[Alpha]_] = 
  3 \[Alpha] \[Pi]^2 rh + 1/2 \[Pi]^2 rh^3 // Simplify;
V[rh_] = (\[Pi]^2 rh^4)/2 // Simplify;
\[Phi][rh_, Q_] = (\[Pi] Q)/(16 rh^2) // Simplify;
M[rh_, Q_, \[Alpha]_, P_] = 
  1/8 \[Pi] (3 \[Alpha] + 3 rh^2 + 4 P \[Pi] rh^4) + (
    8 rh^2 (\[Phi][rh, Q])^2)/\[Pi] // Simplify;
T[rh_, Q_, \[Alpha]_, P_] = (
   rh (\[Pi]^2 (3 + 8 P \[Pi] rh^2) - 64 (\[Phi][rh, Q])^2))/(
   6 \[Pi]^3 (2 \[Alpha] + rh^2)) // Simplify;
G[rh_, Q_, \[Alpha]_, P_] = 
  M[rh, Q, \[Alpha], 
     P] - (T[rh, Q, \[Alpha], P] S[rh, \[Alpha]]) - (\[Phi][rh, 
       Q] Q) // Simplify;
f[r_, rh_, Q_, \[Alpha]_, P_] = 
  1 + r^2/(
     2 \[Alpha]) (1 - Sqrt[
       1 + (32 \[Alpha] M[rh, Q, \[Alpha], P])/(
        3 \[Pi] r^4) - (\[Alpha] Q^2)/(3 r^6) - (16 \[Pi] \[Alpha] P)/
        3]) // Simplify;
Veff[r_] = f[r, rh, Q, \[Alpha], P] (L^2/r^2 + 1) // FullSimplify;
eqn = L^2 == (r0^3* 
       D[f[r0, rh, Q, \[Alpha], P], 
        r0])/(2 f[r0, rh, Q, \[Alpha], P] - 
       r0 D[f[r0, rh, Q, \[Alpha], P], r0]) // FullSimplify;

sol = Block[{\[Alpha] = 0.01, L = 20, P = 0.02}, 
   Solve[eqn, r0, Reals]];

L = 20; \[Alpha] = 0.01; P = 0.02;

\[Lambda][rh_, Q_] = 
  1/2 Sqrt[(r0 D[f[r0, rh, Q, \[Alpha], P], r0] - 
         2 f[r0, rh, Q, \[Alpha], P]) Veff''[r0]] /. sol // Simplify;

Off[General::munfl, Less::nord]

pplt = ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{T[rh, 0.6, \[Alpha], P], #} & /@ (\[Lambda][rh, 0.6][[{6, 
       7}]])], {rh, 0.01, 8}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.25}, {0.1, 1.3}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

which provides the following output in a minute:

[image: new]

But when I try to vary `Q` using this code:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@
  Flatten[Table[{T[rh, Q, \[Alpha], P], #} & /@ (\[Lambda][rh, 
        Q][[{6, 7}]]), {Q, 0.6, 3, 0.5}], 1], {rh, 0.01, 8}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.25}, {0.1, 1.3}}, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
 Exclusions -> All, PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "NeonColor"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Temperature \[Rule]", FontSize -> 31], 
   Style["Lyapunov Exponent \[Rule]", FontSize -> 31]}, 
 ImageSize -> 1000]
```

It provides me with a result after 30 minutes of waiting. Why does it take such a long time? How can I speed up this code and also get just a single coloured plot instead of two colours in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you will only use parts of the solution, discard the others as soon as possible. Also simplify the solution `sol`.

```
sol = Block[{α = 0.01, L = 20, P = 0.02}, 
   Solve[eqn, r0, Reals][[{6, 7}]] // Simplify];

L = 20; α = 0.01; P = 0.02;

λ[rh_, Q_] = 
  1/2 Sqrt[(r0 D[f[r0, rh, Q, α, P], r0] - 
         2 f[r0, rh, Q, α, P]) Veff''[r0]] /. sol // Simplify;

Off[General::munfl, Less::nord]

pplt = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[
   {T[rh, 0.6, α, P], #} & /@ (λ[rh, 0.6])], {rh, 0.01, 8},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.25}, {0.1, 1.3}},
  AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@
   Flatten[
    Table[{T[rh, Q, α, P], #} & /@ λ[rh, Q],
     {Q, 0.6, 3, 0.5}],
    1],
  {rh, 0.01, 8},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.25}, {0.1, 1.3}},
  AspectRatio -> 0.5,
  Exclusions -> All,
  PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "NeonColor"},
  FrameLabel -> {Style["Temperature \[Rule]", FontSize -> 31],
    Style["Lyapunov Exponent \[Rule]", FontSize -> 31]},
  ImageSize -> 1000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

On my laptop, the [`AbsoluteTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html) for the plot is a little over 10 minutes.

**EDIT:** If each curve is to have a single color,

```
colors = Flatten[
   Transpose[{#, #}] &@{RGBColor[1., 0.4, 0.], 
     RGBColor[0., 0.742291, 0.873126], RGBColor[0.893126, 0.4, 0.767184], 
     RGBColor[0.238758, 0.610466, 1.], RGBColor[0.295048, 0.8, 0.286932]}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate@
  Flatten[
   Table[{T[rh, Q, α, P], #} & /@ λ[rh, Q],
    {Q, 0.6, 3, 0.5}],
   1],
 {rh, 0.01, 8},
 PlotStyle -> colors,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.25}, {0.1, 1.3}},
 AspectRatio -> 0.5,
 Exclusions -> All,
 PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "NeonColor"},
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Temperature \[Rule]", FontSize -> 31],
   Style["Lyapunov Exponent \[Rule]", FontSize -> 31]},
 ImageSize -> 1000,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[colors[[;; ;; 2]], Range[0.6, 3, 0.5],
    LegendFunction -> 
      (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 4, FrameStyle -> Gray] &),
    LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm@Q, 14]],
   {0.8, 0.3}]]
```

[image]